# NestJS TypeORM Imports solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Is there any good solution for [this example](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm)?

Seems like if I have a lot of modules like `photo.module.ts` I need to import `DatabaseModule` in every feature module.

Tried to put it in `app.module.ts` but it doesn't help. Maybe there are some solutions with `forRoot` static import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says in the docs:

> In this article, you'll learn how to create a DatabaseModule based on
>   the TypeORM package from scratch using custom providers mechanism. As
>   a consequence, **this solution contains a lot of overhead that you can
>   omit** using ready to use and available out-of-the-box dedicated
>   @nestjs/typeorm package.

So better use the [`@nestjs/typeorm`](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm) package, see [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database).

---

When you use the `@nestjs/typeorm` package, you have to import `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PhotoEntity])` for each feature module. In each feature module, you only want to register the entities that belong to that feature. This improves the encapsulation.

You tried to register a module in the `AppModule` and wondered why its providers weren't available in the feature modules. Note that a module always has to import a module itself so that it can access its exported providers. The only exception to this are [global modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules). When you annotate a module with the decorator `@Global()` then it will automatically be imported in all modules as long as it is imported at least once (e.g. in your `AppModule`).